# Найти минимальный элемент в первой строке массива

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив случайных чисел 5 на 3. В нем нужно в первой строке найти минимальный элемент. Пока что на ум пришло первую строку отсортировать по убыванию и вывести первый элемент, но не работает сама сортировка

```java
int[][] a = new int[5][3];
int[] b = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
int tmp;
for (int s = a.length - 1; s > 0; s--) {

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] > a[i][j + 1]) {
                tmp = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];
                a[i][j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nОтсорт: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас массив многомерный, а сортируете его как одномерный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошей практикой считается не писать собственные сортировщики, а пользоваться готовыми решениями. Первая (и любая другая) строка сама по себе является одномерным массивом. Вы можете использовать встроенный метод `Arrays.sort` для сортировки в одномерном массиве чисел или объектов, реализующих интерфейс `Comparable` (т. е. для которых описаны правила сравнения между собой). Также для вывода массива в классе `Arrays` есть готовые удобные методы.

```java
int[][] a = new int[5][3];
int[] b = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    }
}

System.out.println();

// выводим первую строку как одномерный массив
System.out.println("первая строка до сортировки");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a[0]));

// сортируем первую строку
Arrays.sort(a[0]);

// проверяем результат сортировки
System.out.println("первая строка после сортировки");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a[0]));

// выводим наименьший элемент (с индексом 0)
System.out.println("минимальный элемент первой строки");
System.out.println(a[0][0]);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, компактнее намного

Comment: В большинстве случаев готовые реализации лучше во всем, выглядят компактнее, обладают богатым функционалом,  работают быстрее и надежнее.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить минимальный или максимальных элемент в строке двумерного массива, можно использовать методы [`IntStream.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--) и [`IntStream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--):

```java
int[][] arr = new int[5][3];

// заполняем массив случайными числами
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(j ->
                arr[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10)));

// находим минимальный и максимальный
// элементы в строке и выводим справа
Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(row -> Arrays.toString(row) +
                " min: " + Arrays.stream(row).min().getAsInt() +
                ", max: " + Arrays.stream(row).max().getAsInt())
        .forEach(System.out::println);

// [4, 7, 5] min: 4, max: 7
// [1, 0, 8] min: 0, max: 8
// [4, 6, 1] min: 1, max: 6
// [7, 4, 4] min: 4, max: 7
// [4, 1, 2] min: 1, max: 4
```